# Using "later" variable in jQuery DataTables

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

My DataTables configuration is something like this:

```js
(function ($) {
    "use strict";
$(document).ready(function () {

    $('#data-table-users').DataTable({
        "processing": true, 
        "serverSide": true, 
        "filter": true, 
        "orderMulti": false, 
        "ajax": {
            "url": "/Users/GetUsersData",
            "type": "POST",
            "datatype": "json"
        },
        "columnDefs":
            [{
                "targets": [0],
                "visible": false,
                "searchable": false
            }],
        "columns": [
            .............................
            {

                "data": "Image",
                "orderable": false,
                "render": function (data, type, row, meta) {
                    var imgSrc;
                    if (data != null) {
                        imgSrc = '"data:image/jpeg;base64,' + atob(data) + '"';
                    }
                    else {
                        imgSrc = "/svg/" + "A" + ".svg";
                    }

                    return '<div><img class="small-img" src=' + imgSrc + '></div>';

                }
            },
            {
                "data": "UserName",
                "render": function (data, type, row, meta) {

                    return '<div class="positioned"> <div class="editable" data-name="userName" contenteditable="true">'
                        + data + '</div > <i class="fa fa-pencil pushright" aria-hidden="true"></i> </div>';
                }
            },
            {
                "data": "FirstName",
                "render": function (data, type, row, meta) {
                    if (data == null)
                        data = "";
                    return '<div class="positioned"> <div class="editable" data-name="userName" contenteditable="true">'
                        + data + '</div > <i class="fa fa-pencil pushright" aria-hidden="true"></i> </div>';
                }
            },
            ............................
        ],
        "order": [[8, "desc"]]

    });
});
})(jQuery);
```

For Image column I have in the Render function:

```
else {
    imgSrc = "/svg/" + "A" + ".svg";
}
```

What I would like is instead of having imgSrc = "/svg/A.svg" is to construct it based on UserName column like so:

```
imgSrc = "/svg/" + userName[0].toUpperCase() + ".svg";
```

How can I do that without changing code on server side? It seems to me that DataTables is rendering UserName cell at a later time, so Image cell is already rendered. Can somehow a trigger be added when UserName is rendered to alter Image cell content?

I can change the values for all cells in Image column after the whole table gets rendered, but somehow I dislike that idea because it might look ugly. So, please, don't suggest that.

Answer (score 0):

Just got it. I can access all data for the current row using row parameter.

So it's just:

```
imgSrc = "/svg/" + row['UserName'][0].toUpperCase() + ".svg";
```